# If $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$, what is minimum of $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

tIf $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$, what is minimum of $A=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$?

This question is related to another question in geometry, where a, b and c are altitudes of triangle(they are supposed to be constant) and x, y and z are distance from point p inside the triangle to related sides. I showed A can be minimum if $x=y=z$, also OP of question proved it in different way. I tried to find it algebraically.I found the sum of distances from P to the side is almost constant, so I tried to answer this question instead;

If $x+y+z=k$ the what is minimum of $A=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$?

This is quite easy if $x+y=k$ and $A=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}$:

$y=k-x$

putting this in A and taking derivative of A and equating it to zero we finally get:

$A_{min}=\frac{k}{{\sqrt[3]{(\frac{k}{2})^2}}\big(k-\sqrt[3]{(\frac{k}{2})^2}\big)}$

Now let $x+y=k-z$ for our question and substitute k with $k-z$ in above relation, you find A for z that must be minimized. Taking derivative and other operations you can find minimum of A. But I think there must be a better algorithm.Any idea for solution of this question?

If $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$, what is minimum of $A=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$?

Comment: The title is contradictory to the first line.

Comment: Can you check your $A_{min}$? If you require $x, y > 0$, then the min happens at $ x = y = \frac{k}{2}$ with value $ A = \frac{8}{ k^2}$. If not, the infimum is 0, occurring as  $ x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow - \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers:

The Lagrangian is

$$L(x,y,z,\lambda)=\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}+\frac1{z^2}+\lambda\left(\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac zc-1\right)$$

which has a critical point satisfying

$$\begin{cases}L_x=-\dfrac2{x^3}+\dfrac\lambda a=0\\[1ex]
L_y=-\dfrac2{y^3}+\dfrac\lambda b=0\\[1ex]
L_z=-\dfrac2{z^3}+\dfrac\lambda c=0\\[1ex]
L_\lambda=\dfrac xa+\dfrac yb+\dfrac zc-1=0\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{a^{1/3}}{a^{-2/3}+b^{-2/3}+c^{-2/3}}\\[1ex]
y=\dfrac{b^{1/3}}{a^{-2/3}+b^{-2/3}+c^{-2/3}}\\[1ex]
z=\dfrac{c^{1/3}}{a^{-2/3}+b^{-2/3}+c^{-2/3}}
\end{cases}$$

The target function $f(x,y,z)=\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}+\frac1{z^2}$ has the bordered Hessian matrix

$$\mathbf H(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix}0&a^{-1}&b^{-1}&c^{-1}\\a^{-1}&6x^{-4}&0&0\\b^{-1}&0&6y^{-4}&0\\c^{-1}&0&0&6z^{-4}\end{bmatrix}$$

whose leading principle minors are all negative (["a sufficient condition for a local minimum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian)), and so the minimum value is

$$\frac{(a^{2/3}b^{2/3}+a^{2/3}c^{2/3}+b^{2/3}c^{2/3})^3}{(abc)^2}$$

Comment: Your second derivative test is not valid when there are constraints. You need to use a bordered Hessian.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer with this consideration.

Comment: $A$ tends to 0 for $x,y,z$ going to infinity, so that the value you have found is not the minimum.

Comment: @user "x, y and z are distance from point p inside the triangle to related sides" and it is impossible going to infinity and if $x$ increase then $y,z$ will decrease

Comment: @user170231, thanks for the great resolution. I checked it numerically on triangles and your answer especially fits with equilateral triangle.It verifies my finding that if P is the center of inscribed circle A will be minimum.

Comment: @Soheils OP mentions the triangle as a "related problem". No restrictions on $x,y,z $ are given.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting to positive $x, y, z$, by a direct application of Holder's inequality:

$$( \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{1}{z^2} ) ( \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} ) ( \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} ) \geq \left[ \frac{1}{a^{2/3}} + \frac{1}{b^{2/3}} + \frac{1}{c^{2/3}} \right]^3 = \frac{(a^{2/3}b^{2/3}+a^{2/3}c^{2/3}+b^{2/3}c^{2/3})^3}{(abc)^2}.$$

Hence, the minimum value of $( \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{1}{z^2} )   $ is $ \frac{(a^{2/3}b^{2/3}+a^{2/3}c^{2/3}+b^{2/3}c^{2/3})^3}{(abc)^2} $.